# Showing static block only to specific customer group

Tags: static-block, customer-group

I have a webshop were I have to hide away the login and create user form, because I only want customers with a specific link to be able to register. When they have registered they will be able to see a category that only they have a link for.
What I want to do is create a static block that contains links to this category, customers dashboard etc. that only logged in users/or users in a specific customer can see.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: are you want to show .... category after register?? which have static block??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` before your block as a conditional and you have scenario 1 fixed.

Also you can use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()` to get the Customer group Id as another conditional before echoing your block. See how to echo a block [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647650/how-to-call-magento-block-in-phtml-template)

Complete code:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == "something") :?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sample_links') ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Remember to define your block in your XML file.