# Issue making static block show to specific customer groups

Tags: static-block, phtml

I'm trying to add a static block to my category pages through Custom Design>Custom Layout Update, that is only visible to a certain customer group. I've already referenced this post, but I'm stuck.

[Showing static block only to specific customer group](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33636/showing-static-block-only-to-specific-customer-group)

Currently, I'm using the following in Custom Layout Update:

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="MYCUSTOMBLOCK" before="-">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my-custom-block</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

On that static block, I'm then calling for a phtml file that I created:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/my-custom-file-name.phtml"}}
```

Here's the contents of the phtml file:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() <> 2) :?>
         <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(163)->toHtml()?><?php endif;?>
```

With BlockID 163 being another static block that I created, which has a jpeg in it.

This isn't working for me, I know I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what. Would it be better for me to just call for the jpeg through the phtml file, instead of calling for a 2nd block? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a CMS block, which calls a regular core/template block, which calls (again) a CMS block... Why not just loading the core/template block in your Layout Update?

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" template="page/my-custom-file-name.phtml" before="-" />
</reference>
```

Make it simple, so possible problems are reduced. Maybe layout object is not being loaded in blocks loaded inside a CMS block, and that's because the `$this->getLayout()` part is not working, just an idea...

Comment: Thanks Raul , this method actually worked! It wasn't working at first, but then I realized I wasn't pulling the template from the right folder, i missed a subfolder "page/html/my-custom-file-name.phtml"